# iOS App keeps crashing when trying to perform segue

Tags: ios, iphone, objective-c

I have a child view controller, which I set up from one of my views like this:

```
UIViewController *viewController = [[CCouponDetailViewController alloc] init];
[self addChildViewController:viewController];
[self.view addSubview:viewController.view];
[viewController didMoveToParentViewController:self];
```

I'm trying to perform a segue from the child view controller and it's crashing the app, and I'm not sure why. I have a segue leading from the child view to the intended view with the proper identifier, and I also have a segue leading from the parent view to the intended view with the same identifier (I wasn't sure which one it needed to be from).

However the app crashes every time it hits this line:

```
[self performSegueWithIdentifier:@"toConfirmPage" sender:button];
```

I also tried creating a parent variable and setting it as the parent view controller, then trying to use the with the segue, like so:

```
UIViewController *parent = self.parentViewController;
[parent performSegueWithIdentifier:@"toConfirmPage" sender:button];
```

I discovered that this doesn't crash the app, but also does not perform the segue. I'm not sure what needs to be done in order to allow the segue to work, any ideas? Thanks!

Comment: You should explain your setup a little more. What do you mean by "child view controller"? Do you have a container view with a child controller embedded in it?

Comment: @rdelmar I added more information about my child view controller.

Comment: What does the error in the console say when your app crashes?

Comment: @CocoaDog I have a couple debug messages leading up to the crash and then it just says "(lldb)" nothing else is printed to the console when it crashed.

Comment: That last  bit of code you posted should work properly if you made the segue ("toConfirmPage") from the parent controller to the confirm controller. That's assuming that code is in the child view controller.

Answer (score 0):

[Edited following clarification by the OP]
Just to summarise how I understand this now.
You have a view controller 'A' that you've added a child view controller 'B' to.
The user clicks on a button in the child VC (A)'s view.
You perform a segue from the child VC (A), which leads to a new view which you want presented instead of the parent 'A'.

So, firstly, does the parent VC 'A' correctly implement the container view method (see 'Managing Child View Controllers in a Custom Container' in UIControllerView documentation).  You shouldn't nest VCs unless you do this.

Secondly, you should call performSegue on the VC you want to disappear, which in this case is the parent VC 'A'.  If it isn't working, check that your variable 'parent' is not nil.

Third option is to set a breakpoint on exceptions ( add exception in the breakpoint list).  This will give you a stack backtrace at the point where the exception occurred.

Hope this helps
Gordon

Comment: I don't want to segue from the first child to the second child, I want to leave the parent-child view altogether and open a completely separate view. The first chunk of code is in the parent view class, and the other 2 are both in the child view class

Answer (score 0):

App will crash if "toConfirmPage" is not set as Identifier in the Attributes for your child Controller.

Also you need to replace `[self.view addSubview:viewController.view];`

with `[self.view addSubview:self.currentClientView];`

Have a look at [Apple Doc on Custom Containers](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/featuredarticles/ViewControllerPGforiPhoneOS/CreatingCustomContainerViewControllers/CreatingCustomContainerViewControllers.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40007457-CH18-SW6)

Last but not least, Please post crash log.Use Pastebin to do provide the log. I think your crash log might also tell you what is wrong.

Comment: The line, [self.view addSubview:viewController.view];, is correct. What makes you think it should be self.currentClientView? What is currentClientView, it's not anywhere in the OP's post?